# Which files do you commit and/or omit from your source control?

Tags: version-control, file

I think we can all agree, when a developer gets a project out of their source control system... it should successfully build.

Question:
What extraneous files do you omit and which are you certain to add?

Comment: I think the questions would be more interesting had I asked "what extraneous files are you certain to add"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything that's generated from the items you check into source control.

Things I check in:

1. Source files (usually .java for me, but can be other languages)
2. 3rd party JARs
3. Configuration XML or .properties
4. HTML, CSS, JSPs for web apps
5. SQL scripts
6. Design (UML) and documentation (Word or HTML)
7. Unit test classes and any data I need to run them

Things I don't:

1. Compiled .class files
2. Generated JAR or WAR files
3. javadocs
4. JUnit report HTML and results

Comment: Base artifacts? Excuse my ignorance, but can you elaborate?

Comment: @NTDLS - I'd guess intermediate artifacts of compilation (e.g., .obj or .class files)

Comment: It mean s- Leave out anything that can be automatically generated from things you are including

Comment: Why not javadocs though?

Comment: I can generate javadocs from the source code.  That is the best way to keep it up to date.  If you want to change the javadocs you should be modifying the source files.  True for all generated artifacts.  Should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to generated files, in Visual Studio I leave out mstest files (.vsdmi), resharper user files, Visual Studio user files (.suo).

Answer (score 1):

Include information about the database schema (diagram), set up queries and other special config params

Answer (score 1):

My global ignore pattern for TortoiseSVN is: `*.vbw *.scc *.vbg */bin */obj *.bak *.user *.suo *.webinfo bin obj *.dll *.pdb *.exe` which covers both VB6 and C#.

Answer (score 0):

I always leave out compiled files, which for me are generally of the `.pyc` variety.